# I cant get the right result from my code, getting odd outputs

Tags: c++, c++14, console-application

I'm trying to write a dice algorithm and count the number of every number that could my dice could roll, but getting odd and wrong result. what is the problem with this code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   cout << "Enter the number of dice: ";
   int n;
   int number[5];
   int dice;
   cin >> n;
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      
      dice = (rand() % 6) + 1;
      
      cout << dice << " ";
      
      if (dice == 1) {
          number[0] += 1;
      }
      else if (dice == 2) {
          number[1] += 1;
      }
      else if (dice == 3) {
          number[2] += 1;
      }
      else if (dice == 4) {
          number[3] += 1;
      }
      else if (dice == 5) {
          number[4] += 1;
      }
      else if (dice == 6) {
          number[5] += 1;
      }
   }
   for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
       cout << "\nThe number of dice " << i + 1 << "is: " << number[i] << "\n";
   }
}
```

Comment: `int number[5];` is an array with 5 elements, you want 6

Comment: You have *two* problems, both related to your array.

Comment: "getting odd and wrong result" is not a problem description. Show actual inputs, expected outputs and explanation why, and actual wrong outputs.

Comment: Shorter: Replace the conditional chain with `number[dice-1] += 1;`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Firstly, isnt it simpler and easier to do
`number[dice-1]++;`
instead of 6 if's.
To fix the problem u have to move number array before Main (if u declare it in Main it has random numbers inside it), U can also do this before running first loop, instead of replacing array declaration.

```
for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
    numbers[i]=0;
```

Below is working code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int n, dice, number[6];//Declaring variables here makes them have 0 instead of random value
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    //Declaring variables here makes them have random value
    /*
    Here it should look like this.
    int n, dice, number[6];
    for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
        number[i]=0;
    */
    cout<<"Enter the number of dice: ";
    cin>>n;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        dice=rand()%6+1;
        cout<<dice<<" ";
        number[dice-1]++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        cout << "\nThe number of dice " << i + 1 << " is: " << number[i] << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: No, moving the variable out of `main()` i.e. making it static is not a fix. That is just a workaround for someone who doesn't know how to simply zero-initialise an automatic array... Also, it doesn't simply 'have random numbers' if uninitialised; it gives the program undefined behaviour, so it must be avoided at all costs. The other answer shows the correct fix, for this one of the two problems with the array's declaration.

Comment: the numbers are *not* random

Comment: Actually, declarating variables globaly, Has some advantages specially when writing one file code, it is very usefull in CP(Comperive Programing). Also declaring variables in main doesn't cause any undefined behavior, it behaves exactly like random number.

Comment: " it behaves exactly like random number. " no it doesnt. This is the prime example of expecting undefined behavior to do something specific, but undefined behavior is just undefined.